# Store variables into a class for use in another class and call constructor into a Header File from Windows form application in c++

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I'm using Windows Forms in c++, because I want to store the variables of the textboxes and comboxes into a class named ***uVariables*** with get and set methods. I developed the same in c# with other characteristics, but now debugging in c++ I saw that the variables were not stored.

For example:
I want to store *paradigm* variable using:

***uVariables.h*** Header file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

class uVariables
{
public:
    const char* paradigm;

    uVariables();
    ~uVariables();

    void setParadigm(const char * p);
    const char * getParadigm();
};
```

***uVariables.cpp*** Source file:

```
#include "uVariables.h"
uVariables::uVariables(){}

void uVariables::setParadigm(const char * p) {
    paradigm = p;
}
const char * uVariables::getParadigm() {
    return paradigm;
}

uVariables::~uVariables(){}
```

Then, for use this into the header file from Windows Form application into a button:

From MyForm.h (taken from the design mode)

```
#include "uVariables.h"
.
.
.

private: System::Void btn_start_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    uVariables variables = new uVariables() // Here I have troubles
}
```

But when I want to make the object, it makes an error saying **no suitable constructor exists to convert from "uVariables *" to "uVariables"**

Comment: change `uVariables variables = new uVariables()` to `uVariables* variables = new uVariables()`

Comment: **You should really avoid mixed mode code.** If you want to do WinForms development, you should really do it in C#. And if you do it in C++/CLI, you should avoid using unmanaged code without good reason. Clearly, you don't have much experience with C++ so it is not a good idea to write mixed-mode code.

Comment: Also, it is not a good idea to mixed C string with C++ code and even worst to mix Unicode char with legacy char (I doubt that you are using UTF8 in your C++ code).

Comment: By the way, what is the reason to use a native class for your variables?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is not C++, it is Microsoft's proprietary language C++/CLI, so standard C++ practices may or may not apply.

Secondly, in C++ you very rarely want to create a class member (or anything else like this:

```
someclass * s = new someclass();
```

you almost always just want to say:

```
someclass s;
```

in the class definition, and then simply let the compiler to create the instance for you. So:

```
class A {
    someclass s;
};
```

then:

```
A a;      // someclass instance  will be created (and disposed of) for you
```